# How do I implement a simple OpenCV operation in Kurento OpenCV module

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, kurento

I am trying to process the frame (&Mat) received in the **process** method of the module. When I try run some simple OPENCV methods e.g. [image]

The module will compile; after : `debuild -us -uc`... 
As stated in the tutorial, I install the generated **.deb** file, successfully.

**BUT** when I run `kurento-media-server -v` I get a list of other installed modules but not the one I am building.

removing the above mentioned code, and doing the process again, the module is installed and recognized by Kurento Media Server.

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: You have a linking problem. The KMS log may be quite useful for understanding the cause of the problem. At startup, KMS logs any problems related to modules being loaded.

Comment: I do believe so too. I am getting the following error :

****/libkmsbasicfiltermodule.so cannot be loaded: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmsbasicfilterimpl.so.0: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6String8allocateEm

I have been searching around but I don't know how I can resolve this.

Comment: What version of OpnCV are your using. All the tests at the Kurento core team are based on 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1.

Comment: I have openCV 3.0.0-alpa, Ubuntu 14.04, KMS 6.0

Comment: changed to opencv 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 but still same issue.

Comment: Easiest way is to use the OpenCV that comes bundled with the Kurento installation. When I try to link my own version of OpenCV (3.0) with my Kurento installation, there seams to be a conflict with the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use the OpenCV that comes bundled with the Kurento installation. Extra configuration is required in terms on symbolic linking when own OpenCV installation is used.